# started roscore with different URI but when launched launch file a new ros core was started

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I was trying to run on one machine two nodes in parallel, so I started the first node with "roscore" and on a different terminal a new roscore with

export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11312
roscore --port 11312

but then when I launched a launch file it looked for the regular roscore

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
saw it wasn't started in the terminal so stsrted it

How can I make my nodes run with the new roscore?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385461/started-roscore-with-different-uri-but-when-launched-launch-file-a-new-ros-core-was-started/) by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2021-08-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you `export ROS_MASTER_URI` in the terminal/Bash session where you ran `roslaunch`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.ros.org/users/2980/nachum/) on 2021-08-31**:
Thanks! solved the problem